# Merging from backgroundThread to mainThread context: delete order random so crashes NSTableView

Tags: swift, core-data, nsfetchedresultscontroller, nstableview

I've got trouble with deleting several objects on a background thread:

```
func delete(hierarchy: Hierarchy) throws {
//        let backgroundThread = self.mainThread
    let hierarchies = try self.hierarchies.reloadFrom(context: backgroundThread)

    let hierarchy = try hierarchy.reloadFrom(context: backgroundThread)
    let hierarchyModel = hierarchy.model!

    // .. doing some checks .. 

    backgroundThread.performAndWait {
        backgroundThread.delete(rootFile)
        backgroundThread.delete(hierarchyModel)
        for (index, model) in hierarchies.model!.hierarchies!.array.enumerated() {
            let hierarchyModel = model as! HierarchyModel
            hierarchyModel.position = Int32(index)
        }

    }

    try backgroundThread.save()
}
```

And then this in a loop:

```
func delete(hierarchies: [Hierarchy]) {
    do {
        for hierarchy in hierarchies {
            try modelController.delete(hierarchy: hierarchy)
        }
    } catch {
        NotificationCenter.default.post(FatalErrorNotification(error: error))
    }
}
```

On save the usual NSFetchedResultsController calls its delegates. Note, that he works on the mainThread.

```
public func controller(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>, didChange anObject: Any, at indexPath: IndexPath?, for type: NSFetchedResultsChangeType, newIndexPath: IndexPath?) {

    print(indexPath, newIndexPath)

    switch type {
    case .insert:
        // ...

    case .delete:
        tableView.removeRows(at: IndexSet(integer: indexPath!.item), withAnimation: .slideRight)

    case .update:
        // ...

    case .move:
        // ...
    }
}
```

I use `mainThread.automaticallyMergeChangesFromParent` to get changes from the backgroundThread to the mainThread. This worked quite well for me so far, until now.
My problem is that during the merge things like this happen:

```
# Merging from background thread, delete order crashes.
Optional([0, 0]) nil
Optional([0, 1]) nil
Optional([0, 2]) nil
```

before it crashes in the fetchedResultsController delegate call. It crashes cause on the third call, there is only row [0, 0] left to remove. So it crashes the app.
Incase I do the deletes on the mainThread the deletes are done one after another:

```
# On mainThread: delete order works.
Optional([0, 0]) nil
Optional([0, 2]) Optional([0, 1])
Optional([0, 1]) Optional([0, 0])
going to end updates.
endUpdates
beginUpdates
Optional([0, 0]) nil
Optional([0, 1]) Optional([0, 0])
going to end updates.
endUpdates
beginUpdates
Optional([0, 0]) nil
going to end updates.
endUpdates
```

which does not crash. What I tried:

- calling save only after all three deletes instead of after each one.
- reverse the order of the deletes.
- changed merge policy(got annoyed)
- wrapped whole delete function in backgroundThread.performAndWait { ... }
- tried to find a method which makes the change go to the mainThread before the delete.

Some more collected deletion orders:

```
# On background thread: lucky.
beginUpdates
Optional([0, 2]) nil
Optional([0, 1]) nil
Optional([0, 0]) nil
going to end updates.
endUpdates

# On background thread: lucky again.
beginUpdates
Optional([0, 2]) nil
Optional([0, 1]) nil
Optional([0, 0]) nil
going to end updates.
endUpdates

# On background thread: unlucky again.
Optional([0, 1]) nil
Optional([0, 0]) nil
Optional([0, 2]) nil

# On background thread: unlucky again.
Optional([0, 0]) nil
Optional([0, 1]) nil
Optional([0, 2]) nil

# On background thread: unlucky on 2nd delete already.
beginUpdates
Optional([0, 1]) nil
Optional([0, 2]) nil
```

I hope somebody can help me fix this. It would be really appreciated, I'm stuck.

```
//
// NSFetchedResultsControllerDelegate
//
public func controllerWillChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    print("beginUpdates")
    tableView.beginUpdates()
}
public func controllerDidChangeContent(_ controller: NSFetchedResultsController<NSFetchRequestResult>) {
    print("going to end updates.")
    tableView.endUpdates()
    print("endUpdates")
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I have found the problem. You can't delete object on a background thread, then reorder things and then expect that the deletes come in the right order to the mainThread.

Comment: What did you do as a workaround, just avoid background contexts? I've been struggling with a good solution to this problem as well. This is never a problem on iOS, on macOS.